# Questions about delta function.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $z \neq 1$ be a complex number. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n. 
\end{align}

We have 
\begin{align}
\frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^{-n}.
\end{align}

If we add the left hand sides of the two equations, then we have 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}} = 0.
\end{align}
If we add the right hand sides of the two equations, then we obtain 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} z^n.
\end{align}
Therefore when $z \neq 1$, we have $\sum_{z=-\infty}^{\infty} z^n= 0$. Do we have $\delta(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} z^n$? How to understand the delta function and analytic continuation? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not true that $(1-z)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ for all $z \neq 1$. The relation is only valid for $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get something like that only in some kind of distributional context. As distribution, you can write, as one version
$$
\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}z^n=\lim_{q\to 1-0}\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}q^{|n|}z^n
=\lim_{q\to 1-0}\frac{1-q^2}{1-q(z+z^{-1})+q^2}
$$
which for $|z|=1$ and away from $z=1$ converges to zero while the integral over the unit circle always evaluates to $2\pi i$. Which is the condition for any sequence approximating (a multiple of) the delta distribution.

---

In the end, regardless of how one sets up the test functions and pairing with them, this identity amounts to one classical fact:

> For smooth enough periodic functions, the Fourier series converges pointwise to the function values.

The pairings with the $z^n$ produce (multiples of) the Fourier series coefficients, and the series summation gives the evaluation of the Fourier series at $z=1$ resp. $t=0$ for $z=e^{it}$.

---

Standard reference for this topic: Carl Offner: [A little harmonic analysis](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~offner/files/harm_an.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The first of your series converges for $|z| < 1$, the second for $|z| > 1$.

In other words, there are no values of $z$ for which it is meaningful to add the two series.

Comment: thank you very much. In some papers of physics, they add the two series (for example, 3.48 and 3.50 implies 3.51 in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.08533v1.pdf)). Therefore I asked this question.